# Remove / Undo Joomla Layout Override

Tags: css, templates, joomla, less, overriding

I'm new to Joomla and working on customizing a theme. I created a layout override for links, and now I seem to be missing color variables in the .less. I can find no information on how to remove or undo the override that I created. This strikes me as especially strange, considering that from what I can gather creating a layout override should create a new php file rather than overwriting a less file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to delete the layout override file from your templates HTML/ directory.  If you would like to preserve the file just in case, you can also rename it to something other than default.php.